# Concatenate one column over a resultset like kind of group_concat

Tags: sparql, group-concat, graphdb

I am currently writing on a SPARQL query (GraphDB) and try to concatenate the results of one column to avoid the kind of "duplicates".

My current query looks like this

```
SELECT ?label ?otaupdater
WHERE {
 ?charger rdf:type mymodel:SoftwarePackage. 
 ?charger mymodel:isCompatibleWith ?target.
 ?target car:CarId <93718293>.
 ?charger rdfs:label ?label.
 ?otaupdater rdf:type mymodel:OTAUpdater.
 ?charger mymodel:isCompatibleWith ?otaupdater.
}
```

which gives me a resultset like

| label | otaupdater |
| --- | --- |
| Chargie_One | 123 |
| Chargie_One | 456 |
| Chargie_Two | 123 |

I tried to work in the command group_concat but only got so far that I ended up with

```
SELECT (group_concat(?otaupdater; separator=", ") AS ?otaupdaters) where { ... }
```

but this only returns all otaupdaters in one builded list.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

| label | otaupdaters |
| --- | --- |
| Chargie_One | 123, 456 |
| Chargie_Two | 123 |

Comment: you also have to build a group on the charger: `select ?label (group_concat(...) as ?otaupdaters) where { ... } group by ?label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of @UninformedUser
lead to the answer:

```
SELECT ?charger ?label ?target (group_concat(?otaupdater; separator=", ") AS ?otaupdaters)
WHERE {
 ?charger rdf:type mymodel:SoftwarePackage. 
 ?charger mymodel:isCompatibleWith ?target.
 ?target car:CarId <93718293>.
 ?charger rdfs:label ?label.
 ?otaupdater rdf:type mymodel:OTAUpdater.
 ?charger mymodel:isCompatibleWith ?otaupdater.
}
GROUP BY ?charger ?label ?target
```